# What is the fastest way to see if an array has two common elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, duplicates, c++17

Suppose that we have a very long array, of, say, `int` to make the problem simpler.

What is the fastest way (or just *a* fast way, if it's not *the* fastest), in C++ to see if an array has more than one common elements in C++?

To clarify, this function should return this:

```
[2, 5, 4, 3] => false
[2, 8, 2, 5, 7, 3, 4] => true
[8, 8, 5] => true
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 7, 1, 1, 7, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4] => true
[9, 1, 12] => false
```

One strategy is to loop through the array and for each array element loop through the array again to check. However, this can be very costly and expensive (literally `O(n^2)`). Is there any better way?

Comment: It depends on constraints. With no constraints `std::unordered_set` should do the job. If there are some extra constraints then there are other crafty ways.

Comment: If the language was not C++, how would you perform this in a fast way?  This is a data structure / algorithm question, and not actually tied to C++.

Comment: Yep. Create a set from the vector and, if the size of the set is not the same as the size of the vector, then there are duplicates.

Comment: You could sort the array and then iterate once to see if there is a duplicate entry. You could implement the sorting yourself and return early if two elements are compared and identical. You could iterate once and put the elements into something like a HashSet which has constant time “contains” checks…

Comment: Why does the question mention two arrays???

Comment: If the array is **very** long (>2^32 in your case), the fastest way is `true`.

Comment: @DavisHerring but only in platform where int is 4 bytes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(<sup>✠</sup>Update Below) Insert the array elements to a [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) and if the [insertion fails](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/emplace), it means you have duplicates.

Something like as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

bool has_duplicates(const std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    std::unordered_set<int> set;
    for (int ele : vec)
        if (const auto [iter, inserted] = set.emplace(ele); !inserted)
            return true; // has duplicates!
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec1{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_duplicates(vec1) << '\n'; // false

    std::vector<int> vec2{ 12, 3, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_duplicates(vec2) << '\n'; // true
}
```

---

**<sup>✠</sup>Update**: As discussed in the comments, this can or may not be  the fastest solution. In OP's case, as explained in [*Marcus Müller*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69066787/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-see-if-an-array-has-two-common-elements/69066972#69066972)'s answer, an`O(N·log(N))` method would be better, which we can achieve by having a sorted array check for dupes.

Here is a [quick benchmark that I made for the two cases "*UnorderedSetInsertion*" and the "*ArraySort*"](https://quick-bench.com/q/77BiZfCEntIqGiMRv76XYNoxXrM). Following are the result for *GCC 10.3, C++20, O3*:

[image]

Comment: I agree  , I do not see a better way to do it than a linear time algorithm .

Comment: Note that I don't ascribe too much meaning to Landau symbols in practical problems – for small vectors that fit into L1/L2, doing a bubblesort that aborts when it hits a duplicate will be faster, although of course asymptotically, bubblesort is catastrophic. Your algorithm is nice and linear-time – until your buckets get large and you need to get memory for them. *I don't believe this is actually linear in complexity in practice*, just because the core algorithm looks as if it is – that ignores the memory allocation problem, and the fact that you're doing very irregular memory access patterns.

Comment: this doesn't even go into things like the fact that an in-place sorter needs no extra setup, or that your CPU's branch predictor and your compiler's ability to instruct conditional moves will be *very* happy to optimize the hell out of bubblesort, but won't be very happy about mapping things into buckets. Oh, and constant time: there's large constants, compared to small N :)

Comment: It throws out the unordered set, but counting keeps it O(n), and sidesteps your concern. But I don't think your concern really means bubble sort will eventually end up on top like you imply. An O(n^2) sort falls apart at larger data sets, and it does so much more spectacularly than a few memory allocations.

Comment: The counting doesn't keep it O(n) - it only has effect for some best cases, such as one of the duplicated elements near the front of the array.   Since `std::set::emplace()` is O(log N)  (where N is the size of the set),  the loop will be O(n log n) in the average and worst cases (e.g. the case with no duplicates).

Comment: @JeJo that's super cool! Could I, I'd upvote your answer twice!!

Comment: The third benchmark for `ArraySort` is exceptionally misleading. The array is sorted on the first pass/timing of `has_duplicates3`, meaning that all subsequent passes/timings are only timing how long the lookup is in a *sorted* array. That first slow pass would effectively have very little contribution to the actual timing. It's not a bad thing to benchmark, but it isn't independent like the other tests are.

Comment: A less-misleading benchmark for this would be something [like this](https://quick-bench.com/q/G1LTPV4D73RG7Lh40vP2kld0LGs) which measures the actual cost of sorting it, along with the lookup cost. This benchmark demonstrates what the cost would be to arbitrary/constantly changing data, whereas the current benchmark is more demonstrative of the cost of repeated lookups on the same / infrequently-changed data-set (which allows it to be sorted first, and stay-sorted). It's still faster, but it's less significant.

Comment: @Human-Compiler interestingly if you modify your version of the benchmark to have a set with number of buckets equal to the array size (a bit pessimistic but it will guarantee no re-hash since the constructor (1) will set the max loading factor to 1 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/unordered_set) the difference between the two ways is within the 10%

Answer (score 5):

This is *nearly* just a sorting problem, just that you can abort the sorting once you've hit a single equality and return true.

So, if you're memory-limited (That's often the case, not actually time-limited), an in-place sorting algorithm that aborts when it encounters to identical elements will do; so, `std::sort` with a comparator function that raises an exception when it encounters equality. Complexity would be O(N·log(N)), but let's be honest here: the fact that this is *probably* less indirect in memory addressing then the creation of a tree-like bucket structure might help. In that sense, I can only recommend you actually compare this to JeJos solution – that looks pretty reasonable, too!

The thing here is that there's very likely not a one-size-fits-all solution: what is fastest will depend on the amount of integers we're talking about. Even quadratic complexity might be better than any of our "clever" answers if that keeps memory access nice and linear – I'm almost certain your speed here is not bounded by your CPU, but by the amount of data you need to shuffle to and from RAM.

Answer (score 1):

How about binning data (or create a histogram), and check for mode of the resultant data. A mode > 1 indicates a repeat value.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.