# Return true for duplicate elements

Tags: c++, c++14

I want this boolean function to return true if the array contains any duplicate element and false if it doesn't.  My code is:-

```
bool containsDuplicate(vector<int>& nums) {
        int flag=0;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.size()/2;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<nums.size();j++)
            {
                if(nums[i]==nums[j])
                {
                    flag=1;
                }
            }
        }
    if(flag==1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    
    }
```

It works for arrays containing duplicates but it is not returning false in the case of arrays having unique elements.

Comment: Offtopic: Please don't write `if(condition) return true; else return false;` but simply `return condition;` instead.

Comment: In your case you could drop the `flag` entirely and just return from the function prematurely if the condition is met: `for() { for() { if() { return true; } } } return false;` – avoids needlessly continuing iteration on having found a duplicate already.

Comment: This will fail: "1 2 3 4 5 6 6"

Answer (score 5):

Your solution has time complexity `O(n^2)`. It will be great for small data, but for larger datasets it will be slow.

Extra data structure can greatly improve speed:

```cpp
bool containsDuplicate(const vector<int>& nums) {
    std::unordered_set<int> seen;
    for (auto x : nums) {
        if (!seen.insert(x).second) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[std::unordered_set<Key,Hash,KeyEqual,Allocator>::insert - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert#Return_value)

> #### Return value
>
> 1-2) Returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element (or to the element that prevented the insertion) and a bool denoting whether the insertion took place.

Since inserting into `std::unordered_set` has `O(1)` time complexity, total time complexity of this solution is `O(n)`. Performance maniac could add arbitrary constant which will determine which algorithm use depending on data size (as mentioned your approach will be great for small data).

Comment: Oh, like that one – the price for is additional memory, but in generally worth it (unless perhaps on a micro controller...)

Comment: A potential O(n\*log(n)) alternative is sorting the vector (in place!) – *if* order of contents is irrelevant anyway, of course...

Comment: Yes assuming that you can modify data.

Comment: Oh, return values should be *inverse*: `containsDuplicate` -> insertion failes -> there's a duplicate -> `return true`...

Comment: BTW this is not guaranteed to be the fastest. See the two answers: **[What is the fastest way to see if an array has two common elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69066787/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-see-if-an-array-has-two-common-elements)**

Comment: Fully correct would be: *'[...] has amortised O(1) time complexity'* to account for potential re-allocations occur – [`reserve`ing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/reserve) would avoid that.

Comment: @JeJo yes I've broken "Measure First" rule :/.

Comment: Can you solve it in linear time and space?

Comment: @UTKARSHLUCIFER this is linear in time and space. Did you mean in constant space complexity?

Answer (score 2):

You are testing the first half of elements against themselves, and not testing duplicates in the second half. You should instead test every element against *later* elements

```
bool containsDuplicate(const vector<int>& nums) {
    for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<nums.size();j++)
        {
            if(nums[i]==nums[j])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: Though I personally prefer `for(i = 1; ...) { for(j = 0; j < i; ...) { ... } }` for not having to call `size` function again and again in inner loop at least ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua I'd leave that sort of thing to the optimiser

Comment: Why? If we can write more efficient code with even less pain (mine is shorter... – and the pain: I left the call to `size` in the outer loop for exactly that reason...)? And how far would we want to rely on the optimiser at all then? My favourite (counter-) example: Update only existing: `if(map.find(key) { map[key] = newVal; }` instead of re-using the iterator returned...

Comment: @Aconcagua "that sort of thing", not "everything". I'm reasonably confident that hoisting constants above a loop is one of the things that the implementations I use do. I'm not confident that they merge map lookups

Comment: I can't proof it but I have the (probably wrong) feeling that `for(j = 0; j < i; ++j)` is more likely to find a duplicate early. Or at least faster because it starts with small loops where all data fits in cache and can cover a big chunk of the search space before before it exceeds L1, L2, L3 cache. The other way around it starts of exceeding caches and then slowly gets down to fit in L3, L2, L1 caches. And if it exits early (likely if there is a duplicate) it's best to start fast.

Comment: Maybe I should have argumented *'for its brevity'* right from the start ;) Never mind. My personal attitude is: Don't rely on the optimiser *unless* not doing so would lead to more complicated code – *then* we're in the field of premature optimisations...

Comment: How about: `for (const auto & i : nums) { for (const auto & j : nums) { if (&i == &j) break; if (i == j) return true; } } return false;`?

Comment: Well if I were writing this it'd be `template <class ForwardIt> bool containsDuplicates(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)` and there'd be no `size()` calls

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow or `(&i != &j) && (i == j)`

Comment: @Caleth the `break` exits the inner loop when i and j are the same object. It's the `for(j = 0; j < i; ++j)` written in an odd way. Your case would only skip the same-object case but not break the loop.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow About finding early: Duplicates being on long distances (more than half the data length or so) then then original variant is in advantage. Amortised over arbitrary data with both short and long distances the caching likely comes into play...

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow The range based approach results in many duplicate checks, it would correspond to `for(i = 0; i < num; ++i) { for(j = 0; j < num; ++j) { } }` but iterator-based...

Comment: @Aconcagua No it doesn't. It breaks the inner loop so every comparison is unique. It's the same as: `for(i = 0; i < num; ++i) { for(j = 0; j < num; ++j) { if (i == j) break; ... } }` At least that's the design goal, might be buggy.

Comment: I often wish for an iterator/index based range loop, maybe like: `for (auto *it : nums)`, where `it` is an iterator instead of a value.